# how to disable existing dates from ngbdatepicker angular

Tags: angular, ngb-datepicker

I have array existing data. how to disable existing data when picking date from ngbdatepicker?

here's my disable code from past date

```
var current = new Date();
current.setDate(current.getDate());
this.minDates = {
                  year: current.getFullYear(),
                  month: current.getMonth() + 1,
                  day: current.getDate(),

                };
```

this is my code for existing dates array

```
var avDateArray = [];
 for(var i=0;i<this.tmpResponse[0].available_date.length;i++){
                  avDateArray.push(this.tmpResponse[0].available_date[i].start_date);
                }
```

what i confuse is how to disable date from existingdates array in ngbdatepicker in angular?

Answer (score 4):

just create an array with the disabled dates

```
disabledDates:NgbDateStruct[]=[
    {year:2019,month:2,day:26}
  ]
```

And create a function "isDisabled"

```
  isDisabled=(date:NgbDateStruct,current: {month: number,year:number})=> {
    //in current we have the month and the year actual
    return this.disabledDates.find(x=>new NgbDate(x.year,x.month,x.day).equals(date))?
         true:false;
  }

  //or briefly

  isDisabled=(date:NgbDateStruct,current: {month: number,year:number})=>
    this.disabledDates.find(x=>new NgbDate(x.year,x.month,x.day).equals(date))?true:false;
```

Your ngb-datepicker use [markDisabled]

```
<ngb-datepicker #dp [(ngModel)]="model" (navigate)="date = $event.next"
      [markDisabled]="isDisabled"></ngb-datepicker>
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w9p97r?file=app%2Fdatepicker-basic.html)

Answer (score 1):

**Disabling and limiting dates**

You can limit the dates available for navigation and selection using [minDate] and [maxDate] inputs. If you don't specify any of them, you'll have infinite navigation and the year select box will display [-10, +10] years from currently visible month.

If you want to disable some dates for selection (ex. weekends), you have to provide the [markDisabled] function that will mark certain dates not selectable. It will be called for each newly visible day when you navigate between months.

```
// disable the 13th of each month
const isDisabled = (date: NgbDate, current: {month: number}) => day.date === 13;
<ngb-datepicker [minDate]="{year: 2010, month: 1, day: 1}"
                [maxDate]="{year: 2048, month: 12, day: 31}"
                [markDisabled]="isDisabled">
</ngb-datepicker>
```

Refer the following link also:
[Mark-disabled-ng-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47738545/mark-disabled-ng-bootstrap-not-working-with-other-datepickers-examples)

[ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview)

Comment: Please be aware that the function needs to be an arrow function like in the example, otherwise "this" is not bound to the class context when the function is called from the datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to disable past dates? You can do something like this:

On your component.ts

```
minDate = undefined;
.
. 
constructor(private config: NgbDatepickerConfig) {
  const current = new Date();
  this.minDate = {
    year: current.getFullYear(),
    month: current.getMonth() + 1,
    day: current.getDate()
  };

}
.
.
markDisabled(date: NgbDateStruct) {
  const d = new Date(date.year, date.month - 1, date.day);
  return d.getDate()===this.disabledDate.getDate() && d.getMonth()===this.disabledDate.getMonth && d.getYear()===this.disabledDate.getYear()
  })
}
```

and on your component.html, use the `[minDate]` input binding to disable past dates, and `[markDisabled]` input binding to disable the dynamic list of dates

```
<input class="form-control" ngbDatepicker [minDate]="minDate"  [markDisabled]="markDisabled" (click)="datePicker.toggle()" #datePicker="ngbDatepicker" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd">
```

Comment: no, i want to disable existing date. i already done with disabling past dates

Comment: GImme a few minutes, I am updating my ans. Sorry about that

Comment: I have updated my answer, but just to clarify, are the dates on your list in Date object format? Or is it in some other format, such as string?

Answer (score 0):

This Works for my:

```
<ngb-datepicker #dp 
     (dateSelect)="onDateSelection($event)" 
     [displayMonths]="2" 
     outsideDays="hidden" 
     [markDisabled]="markDisabled"/>



markDisabled(date: NgbDateStruct) {
const dateFixed = new Date(date.year, date.month-1 , date.day);
let today = new Date();

let ifMinusToday = () => {
  if(dateFixed.getFullYear() < today.getFullYear())
    return true;
  else if(dateFixed.getMonth() < today.getMonth())
    return true;
  else if(dateFixed.getMonth() == today.getMonth() && dateFixed.getDate() < today.getDate())
    return true;
    
  return false;
}

return ifMinusToday();
```

}